# Cannot install ruby gem behind proxy

Tags: ruby, proxy, vagrant

I have configured my http_proxy variable, and am able to use curl, and apt-get, etc.  However, when trying to run a command such as `gem install bundler` I get a proxy error.  Is there something different I need to do in order to get Ruby to respect the proxy like every other tool is doing?

```
$ gem install --debug -V bundler
Exception `NameError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:177 - uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
Exception `Errno::EAGAIN' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141 - Resource temporarily unavailable - read would block
407 Proxy Authentication Required
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:222 - bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:242 - bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
Error fetching remote data:
bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
Falling back to local-only install
Exception `Gem::GemNotFoundException' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:237 - Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0) locally or in a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0) in any repository
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
Exception `Errno::EAGAIN' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141 - Resource temporarily unavailable - read would block
407 Proxy Authentication Required
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:222 - bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:242 - bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:222:in `fetch_http'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:238:in `fetch_path'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:269:in `load_specs'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:231:in `block in list'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:227:in `each'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:227:in `list'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:189:in `suggest_gems_from_name'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command.rb:160:in `show_lookup_failure'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:132:in `rescue in block in execute'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:116:in `block in execute'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:115:in `each'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:115:in `execute'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command.rb:278:in `invoke'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:147:in `process_args'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:117:in `run'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:65:in `run'
        /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The error is **407 Proxy Authentication Required**.  Do you need to authenticate to use the proxy?

Comment: I authenticate by using the format:
export http_proxy=http://myusername:mypassword@proxyhost:proxyport

Answer (score 9):

Just some more precision.
Your `407 Proxy Authentication Required` error means you have to **use a login and password for your proxy**.

You can use the `--http-proxy` option to add it, with the following pattern:

```
gem install --http-proxy http://login:password@proxyServer:proxyPort yourGem
```

BUT, **this will not work if your password contains some special character**.
Effectively, as **the option value must match an URL**, some characters are forbidden.

If you are unsure, instead of specifying the proxy in the `gem install` command, you can do in the shell, before executing the command, with:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyServer:proxyPort
set HTTP_PROXY_USER=login
set HTTP_PROXY_PASS=password
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxyServer:proxyPort
set HTTPS_PROXY_USER=login
set HTTPS_PROXY_PASS=password
```

Comment: To work around the problem of a password containing special character, it is necessary to 'URL encode' it. For example, a password containing **+** character must be inserted as **%2B**

Comment: I do agree. Characters not supporterd in URL can be replaced by their equivalent in [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).
Something like `https://user:p@ssword@github.com/user/repo.git` would become `https://user:p%40ssword@github.com/user/repo.git`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

sudo HTTP_PROXY="http://10.3.100.207:8080" gem install bundler

Replace "10.3.100.207" with your proxy and "8080" with your port value"

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the http-proxy setting to your ~/.gemrc file.

Example gemrc

```
--- 
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
http-proxy: http://example.com:80
```

Comment: Didn't work :(  ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407 (http://rubygems.org/latest_s
pecs.4.8.gz)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by downloading and configuring ntlmaps.  Worked great.  For some reason the gemrc file proxy did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the proxy environment variables in the `.bashrc` file of your home user folder:

Add these lines at the end of your .bashrc

```
export http_proxy="http://proxy:80"
export https_proxy="http://proxy:80"
```

Remembert to open a new shell window, so the shell can reload the `.bashrc` file.

If you are using sudo there's an option to use the environment vars of the user as root, edit your `/etc/sudores` file and add this line:

```
Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy"
```

If you need proxy authentication on a microsoft proxy, i recommend the cntlm proxy: http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/

By default cntlm uses the 3128 port, so you have to change the environment variables of `.bashrc`:

```
export http_proxy="http://localhost:3128"
export https_proxy="http://localhost:3128"
```

To configure cntlm it is pretty self explanatory, here you are the important options:

```
#
# Cntlm Authentication Proxy Configuration
#
# NOTE: all values are parsed literally, do NOT escape spaces,
# do not quote. Use 0600 perms if you use plaintext password.
#

Username        testuser
Domain          corp-uk
Password        password
# NOTE: Use plaintext password only at your own risk
# Use hashes instead. You can use a "cntlm -M" and "cntlm -H"
# command sequence to get the right config for your environment.
# See cntlm man page
# Example secure config shown below.
# PassLM          1AD35398BE6565DDB5C4EF70C0593492
# PassNT          77B9081511704EE852F94227CF48A793
### Only for user 'testuser', domain 'corp-uk'
# PassNTLMv2      D5826E9C665C37C80B53397D5C07BBCB

# Specify the netbios hostname cntlm will send to the parent
# proxies. Normally the value is auto-guessed.
#
# Workstation   netbios_hostname

# List of parent proxies to use. More proxies can be defined
# one per line in format <proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>
#
Proxy           10.0.0.41:8080
Proxy           10.0.0.42:8080
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me what @thomas mentioned worked ...

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyServer:proxyPort
set HTTP_PROXY_USER=login
set HTTP_PROXY_PASS=password
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxyServer:proxyPort
set HTTPS_PROXY_USER=login
set HTTPS_PROXY_PASS=password
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

> gem install --http-proxy
>   http://**proxy-User**:**Pass**@**Proxy-Name**:**Proxy-Port**
>   gem-XYZ

Your pass need be simple, without special characters or will return an error.